# Installing aws php sdk with phar

Tags: php, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, phar, suhosin

I am trying to use the AWS SDK for PHP 2 to create a file on S3.

Installing via Phar:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awssdkdocsphp2/latest/gettingstartedguide/sdk-php2-installing-the-sdk.html#sdk-php2-installing-via-phar

I added the following line to "/etc/php5/conf.d/suhosin.ini":

```
suhosin.executor.include.whitelist = phar
```

I restarted apache and the aws.phar include worked as intended. However, without changing anything, on further attempts it seems like the server doesn't send a response and Chrome displays the "no data received" error.

Everytime I restart apache it returns a response, but not on subsequent loads.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Using Laravel, PHP 5.3.2 and Ubuntu.

**UPDATE**
The same thing seems happens with or without the suhosin.ini edit.

Even when the server doesn't return a response to the web browser, the code seems to run properly because it creates a file on S3.

Comment: Does the script normally run a long time? Are you using a cgi/fcgi configuration of php?

Comment: The script just creates a text file and takes less than a second to run. No cgi/fcgi config as far as I know.

Comment: If you are looking for a response in the browser, you do have php configured with a web server in some way. No data received error can sometimes result from php running in a cgi/fcgi configuration not returning anything to the web server. I would also check any related error logs to see if php is crashing for some reason.

Comment: How do you explain that the first time the script runs after an apache restart, it returns a response but without changing anything (hitting refresh on the website) it returns an empty response? Also no related errors in the php error log. Anywhere else I should be looking? Right now I'm not even sure what's causing the issue.

Comment: You could be getting a segmentation fault on the second request. This may be something that should show up on an apache error log if its happening.

Comment: Run your PHP script from the command line if you can. I'm having a problem with the Amazon PHP SDK (v. 2) and only discovered a segmentation fault by doing this. The response to a browser just showed the generic "internal server error" (500) page.